# Magento configurable product stock =0

Tags: magento

I have this custom code in my list.phtml to display an image when product qty goes 0:

```
    <?php $stock_count = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
if ($stock_count <1) {

    echo '<span style="position:relative;top:-230px;float:right;"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/ico_outofstock.png" border=0></span>';


} 
?>
```

Problem is that if product is Configurable it will still display the out of stock image.

What i need is to add something like

```
if($_product->isConfigurable()) {
```

to the above code, so the outofstock image will be displayed only for simple products.
Thanks

Comment: `$_product->isConfigurable()` actually exists, if this is what you're looking for ?

Comment: i know it exists. how will i connect my script with if($_product->isConfigurable()) { so it will check if is configurable and will not display out of stock image.